# How to run one-time task automatically after few second

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to call a task that runs automatically after a few seconds in winform.

but I realized there is no events that occurred after the form was completely opened.

so how can I call some task after form was completely opened and after few seconds?? (just one-time)

Comment: You can use a timer control.. create event handler for Timer.Elapsed event.  start the timer when form opens... and write the code of task in timer.Elapsed event. And disabled the timer once the the code is executed.

Comment: Handle `Form.Shown`, make the handler async then `await Task.Delay(aFewSecondsInterval);`. When it returns, run the Task.